# Piechart-how to wrap the words

Tags: plotting

In my pie chart, it's almost there.

Can I wrap some words?

like putting "Profit versus Objectives" t0 three lines,

but still in the right sector.

```
PieChart[{1/6 - 0.02, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6 - 0.03, 1/6 + 0.03, 1/6 + 0.02}, 
ChartLabels -> {"Profit versus Objectives", "Profitability Level", 
"Payback Period", "Relative Sales", "Relatives Profits", 
"Sales versus Objectives"}, ChartStyle -> {White}, 
PlotLabel -> "Fianacial Performance", 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 11, 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `ChartStyle -> White` and `LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 24)`  or `LabelStyle ->24`?

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out. Is it possible to wrap the words a bit?

Comment: Try using \n inside the quotes. Does this wrap as you wish?

Comment: "Profit\nversus\nObjectives" in place of "Profit versus Objectives" seems to do it.

Comment: You can also use `ChartLabels->Pane[#, 70] & /@ { ...labels...}` or `ChartLabels->Row[{#}, 70] & /@ { ...labels...}`

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping labels in `Pane` often helps in charts:

```
labels = Pane[#, ImageSize -> 80] & /@ {"Profit versus Objectives", 
    "Profitability Level", "Payback Period", "Relative Sales", 
    "Relatives Profits", "Sales versus Objectives"};

PieChart[{1/6 - 0.02, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6 - 0.03, 1/6 + 0.03, 1/6 + 0.02}, 
 ChartLabels -> labels, ChartStyle -> {White}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Fianacial Performance", 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 11, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

[image]

The benefit of using something like `Pane` is that you can make all labels the same image size and do not have to worry about manually placing line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Using newline ("\n") as the delimiter in the labels rather than space (" ") seems to produce a good-looking pie chart.

```
PieChart[ConstantArray[1/6, 6], 
  ChartLabels -> {
    "Profit\nversus\nObjectives", "Profitability\nLevel", "Payback\nPeriod", 
    "Relative\nSales", "Relatives\nProfits", "Sales\nversus\nObjectives"}, 
  ChartStyle -> {White}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Financial Performance", 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 11, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

[image: pie.png]