# Vertex Labelling and Word wrap

Tags: graphs-and-networks, string-manipulation, labeling

I am having trouble formatting vertex labels, explicitly adding line breaks to Vertex labels for word wrapping and other purposes.  I have explored the pane option suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/piechart-how-to-wrap-the-words) but when I include StringReplace it starts throwing errors although still gives the required result.  I suspect its due to incomplete understanding of what "Names" does.

My example is as follows - note I'm creating an Org chart hence the custom (and somewhat "wordy" EdgeLayout.

I realise I can probably get a more complex Vertex label by using Table and a replacement rule - but I'll also need a simpler form for other purposes so it would be good to fix this one first.

So 2 parts to my question.

How to avoid the errors?
Whats actually passed to a function when "Names" is used?

```
    wrapLabel[lbl_] := StringReplace[lbl, ":" -> "\n"];

    Graph[{"Melvyn:GRU"-> "Gordon:Minion 1","Melvyn:GRU"->"Philip:Minion 2"},
    {GraphStyle->"SmallNetwork",
    EdgeShapeFunction->  (*Edges consist of 3 pairs of 2d cords to create a typical Org Chart style 3 Line Edge *)({Line[{#1[[1]](*1st pair*),{#1[[1,1]],#1[[1,2]]-(#1[[1,2]]-#1[[2,2]])/2}(*2nd pair*),{#1[[1,1]],#1[[1,2]]-(#1[[1,2]]-#1[[2,2]])/2}(*3rd pair*),{#1[[2,1]],(#1[[1,2]]-(#1[[1,2]]-#1[[2,2]])/2)}(*4th pair*),{#1[[2,1]],(#1[[1,2]]-(#1[[1,2]]-#1[[2,2]])/2)}(*5th pair*),#1[[2]] (*6th pair*)}]}&),
    EdgeStyle-> {DirectedEdge["Melvyn:GRU","Gordon:Minion 1"]->Dashed },
    ImageSize->{1200,Automatic},
    GridLinesStyle->Directive[GrayLevel[0.5,0.4]],
    VertexLabels->{Placed["Name",Center,wrapLabel]},
    VertexShapeFunction->{"RoundedRectangle"},
    VertexStyle->{"Philip:Minion 2"-> Green}}]
```

Error given

```
    String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringReplace[\!\\(#2, \":\" -> \"\\\\n\"\)].
```

Comment: I don't get any error from running your code (Mma v9). The resulting graph is blank, though

Comment: Change the definition of wrapLabel to `wrapLabel[lbl_String] := StringReplace[lbl, ":" -> "\n"];`

Comment: Running this in MMA 10. @BobHanlon that works as a function (and is most educational for me) note that it throws additional errors that kguler has dealt with. - Correction - just running a clear all and now not getting errors just from Bob's simple change - weird.

Comment: Until you cleared the previous definition of wrapLabel it was used before the new definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[wrapLabel];
wrapLabel[lbl_] := StringReplace[lbl, ":" -> "\n"];
vlist={"Melvyn:GRU", "Gordon:Minion 1",  "Philip:Minion 2"};

options = {GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", 
   EdgeShapeFunction ->
  (*Edges consist of 3 pairs of 2d cords to create a typical Org Chart style 3 Line Edge*)
   ({Line[{#1[[1]](*1st pair*), 
     {#1[[1, 1]], #1[[1, 2]] - (#1[[1, 2]] - #1[[2, 2]])/ 2}(*2nd pair*), 
     {#1[[1, 1]], #1[[1, 2]] - (#1[[1, 2]] - #1[[2, 2]])/ 2}(*3rd pair*),
     {#1[[2, 1]], (#1[[1, 2]] - (#1[[1, 2]] - #1[[2, 2]])/2)}(*4th pair*),
     {#1[[2, 1]], (#1[[1, 2]] - (#1[[1, 2]] - #1[[2, 2]])/2)}(*5th pair*),
      #1[[2]] (*6th pair*)}]} &), 
   EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge["Melvyn:GRU", "Gordon:Minion 1"] -> Dashed}, 
   (* ImageSize -> {1200, Automatic},  removed *)
   ImageSize -> {500, 200}, (* added  *)
   VertexSize -> Large, (* added *)
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]],
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center, wrapLabel],
   VertexShapeFunction -> {"RoundedRectangle"}, 
   VertexStyle -> {"Philip:Minion 2" -> Green}};
```

The function `wrapLabel` in the third argument of `Placed`:

```
gg = Graph[{"Melvyn:GRU" -> "Gordon:Minion 1", "Melvyn:GRU" -> "Philip:Minion 2"}, options]
```

gives (without an error message in Version 9, and accompanied by error messages in Version 10)

[image]

**The easiest solution is to change the definition of `wrapLabel` to `wrapLabel[lbl_String]:=...` as suggested by Bob Hanlon in the comments**.

Here are some additional methods that work with OP's definition as is:

**Use an alternative syntax for setting `VertexLabels`**

```
Graph[{"Melvyn:GRU" -> "Gordon:Minion 1", "Melvyn:GRU" -> "Philip:Minion 2"}, 
      VertexLabels -> {x_ :> Placed[wrapLabel[x], Center]}, options]
(* or VertexLabels -> {x_ :> Placed[x, Center,wrapLabel]} *)
```

or

```
Graph[{"Melvyn:GRU" -> "Gordon:Minion 1", "Melvyn:GRU" -> "Philip:Minion 2"}, 
      VertexLabels ->  Placed[# ,Center,wrapLabel]&/@vlist, options]
(* or VertexLabels ->  Placed[wrapLabel@#,Center]&/@vlist *)
```

**Post-process to set the `VertexLabels` using `SetProperty`**

```
wrappedLabelsF = Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2},  VertexLabels -> 
                       Placed[wrapLabel[#2], Center]] &, #, VertexList[#]] &;
wrappedLabelsF@gg
```

**Use the first argument of `Graph` to provide a labeled vertex list using `Property`**

```
Graph[Property[#,  VertexLabels -> Placed[wrapLabel[#], Center]] & /@ vlist,
      {"Melvyn:GRU" -> "Gordon:Minion 1", "Melvyn:GRU" -> "Philip:Minion 2"}, options]
```

All give

[image]

Comment: Amazingly complete solution - just one comment so far, I think the 3rd Argument of Placed can be made to work - ie this works wrapLabel[lbl_]:=Panel[lbl];  so its something to do with the particular string function rather than a fault with Placed/VertexLabels itself.  Can't fault the number of alternative options though.

Comment: @GordonCoale, thank you.. Just noticed Bob Hanlon's comment -- which makes all these 'work-arounds' unnecessary :)

Comment: I think your answer was triply useful as it highlights some alternative approaches that may be useful to me for some of my more complex needs in this area - so its still much appreciated and since you edited it to include Bob's I'll mark this as answered.